# Problem with using NDSolve to solve coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
rmax = 100, g = 3, n = 10^10, B = 160^4, T = 170, r0 = 1.477, L = n/(4/3*pi*r^3) 
a = 1/(20*r0^3), mu = ((6*L*pi^2)/g)^1/3

Er(r) = 3*pr(r) + 4*B - 16/27*mu*T(mu^2 - 2*mu*T + T^2) 

s = 
  NDSolve[
    {m'[r] == a*r^2 Er[r], 
     pr'[r] == -(r0/r)*((pr[r] + Er[r]) (m[r] + a*r^3* pr[r]))/(r - 2 r0*m[r]), 
     m[1] == 1, pr[1] == 1}, 
    {m, pr}, {r, 1, rmax}]
```

It is showing the error

> NDSolve : Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r == 1.

How to solve the problem raised by the message?

Comment: There are many  errors in your code. To begin with, use ";" instead of "," to separate assignements. Use Pi instead of pi. Make sure functions are defined with "[ ]" instead of "( )".

Comment: Check your code:  `Er(r)->Er[r], pr(r)->pr[r], pi->Pi`. The corrected system equations show an infinite slope at `r==1`, that's why `NDSolve` doesn't find a solution!

Comment: Is it a stiff equation kind of thing? Can I plot the function any how???

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

This is not an answer, but an extended comment which reveals the syntax errors that must be corrected before progress can be made on the real problem inherent in the OP's system of equations.

With correct Mathematica syntax, there is no complaint about non-numerical quantities but there is still an error.

```
rmax = 100; g = 3; n = 10^10; B =  160^4; T = 170 ; r0 = 1.477; L = n/(4/3 Pi r^3);
a = 1/(20 r0^3); mu = ((6 L Pi^2)/g)^1/3;

Er[r_] = 3 pr[r] + 4 B - 16/27 mu T (mu^2 - 2 mu T + T^2);

{mF, prF} = 
   NDSolveValue[
     {m'[r] == a r^2 Er[r], 
      pr'[r] == -(r0/r) ((pr[r] + Er[r]) (m[r] + a r^3 pr[r]))/(r - 2 r0 m[r]), 
      m[1] == 1, pr[1] == 1},
     {m, pr}, {r, 1, rmax}];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At r == 1.`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

#### Notes

1. `pi` should be `Pi`.
2. Multiple assignments should be separated with `;` not `,`.
3. `E(r)` needs to be replaced with `E[r_]`.
4. I recommend `NDSolveValue` over `NDSolve` because it returns a list of interpolation functions. I find that result easier to use in further calculations.

Comment: You have missed the L in mu expression while writing the code.

Comment: After inserting mu expression with the missing L it is showing the same problem.

Comment: @Sovan. I missed both the `L` in the definition of `mu` and the `pi` in the definition of `L`. I have made the required edits and revised my conclusions accordingly.

Comment: To address the "At r==1, step size is effectively zero..." issue, the first thing I'd try is adding WhenEvent[r==1,"CrossSlidingDiscontinuity"] and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Using code @m_goldberg and explicit Euler, we can get a solution.

```
rmax = 100; g = 3; n = 10^10; B = 160^4; T = 170; r0 = 1477/100; L = 
 n/(4/3 Pi r^3);
a = 1/(20 r0^3); mu = ((6 L Pi^2)/g)^1/3;

Er[r_] = 3 pr[r] + 4 B - 16/27 mu T (mu^2 - 2 mu T + T^2);

{mF, prF} = 
  NDSolveValue[{m'[r] == a r^2 Er[r], 
    pr'[r] == -(r0/r) ((pr[r] + Er[r]) (m[r] + a r^3 pr[r]))/(r - 
         2 r0 m[r]), m[1] == 1, pr[1] == 1}, {m, pr}, {r, 1, rmax}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 10^-2, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
   Method -> "ExplicitEuler"];

{Plot[mF[r], {r, 1, rmax}], Plot[prF[r], {r, 1, rmax}]}
```

[image: fig1]